# Spring Boot, Hibernate initiates twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I got a problem when using Hibernate and Spring Boot.
Hibernate loads twice, so it creates the DB, then recreates it again (using the hbm2ddl.auto=create, so I expect once).

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {
        UserMapper.class,
        EventMapper.class,
        GroupMapper.class,

        UserServiceImpl.class,
        EventServiceImpl.class,
        GroupServiceImpl.class,

        UserController.class
})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@Import({ DatabaseConfig.class })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And DatabaseConfig:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {
        EventRepository.class,
        GroupRepository.class,
        UserRepository.class
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {
    private static final String DB_DRIVER_CLASS = "db.driver";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String DB_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String DB_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String DB_SSL = "db.ssl";
    private static final String DB_SSL_FACTORY = "db.ssl.factory";
    private static final String DB_FORMAT_SQL = "db.formatSql";
    private static final String DB_DIALECT = "db.dialect";
    private static final String DB_SHOW_SQL = "db.show_sql";
    private static final String DB_HBM2DLL_AUTO = "db.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String DB_POOL_SIZE = "db.poolSize";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan());
        factory.setHibernateProperties(dataSourceProperties());
        factory.setAnnotatedClasses(classesToAdd());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    private DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(DB_DRIVER_CLASS));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(DB_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(DB_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(DB_PASSWORD));
        dataSource.setConnectionProperties(connectionPropertiesDev());
        return dataSource;
    }

    public Class[] classesToAdd() {
        return new Class[]{

        };
    }

    public String[] packagesToScan() {
        return new String[] {""};
    }

    private Properties dataSourceProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_DRIVER_CLASS));
        props.put("hibernate.connection.url", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_URL));
        props.put("hibernate.connection.username", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_USERNAME));
        props.put("hibernate.connection.password", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_PASSWORD));
        props.put("hibernate.connection.pool_size", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_POOL_SIZE));
        props.put("hibernate.connection.requireSSL", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_SSL));
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_HBM2DLL_AUTO));
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_SHOW_SQL));
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_DIALECT));
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_FORMAT_SQL));
        return props;
    }

    private Properties connectionPropertiesDev() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("ssl", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_SSL, Boolean.class));
        properties.put("sslfactory", env.getRequiredProperty(DB_SSL_FACTORY));
        return new Properties();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(dataSourceProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException {
        final HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
        txManager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Maybe because you have a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and a `SessionFactory`? Do you need both? Do you need either (since Boot will create one for you)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others that might do the same mistake as me, the answer Dave Syer came with was correct. 
I checked the http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix and read the whole document.

Just providing the correct config values will get you a long way. Thanks for the help Dave.

Answer (score 1):

Check your web.xml file and make sure that the spring ApplicationContext is not being loaded twice. Make sure that contextConfigurationLocation and appServlet are not the same file. If they are then your application context will be loaded twice. I have asterisks around these lines. I was using the scheduler and as I had the same file in these spots the scheduled tasks ran twice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>FLEX Contacts Mobile Service</display-name>
  <context-param>
    ***<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>***
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      **<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>**
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flex_contacts_mobile_service/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```